# rails is currently not installed after reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a strange problem: I have installed ruby on rails on rvm. Everything is ok, I can create project.. But after rebooting when I typing "rails new " I have "The program 'rails' is currently not installed.".

```
System Ubuntu 12.04

ruby -v
"1.9.3p194"

gem list
actionmailer (3.2.5)
actionpack (3.2.5)
activemodel (3.2.5)
activerecord (3.2.5)
activeresource (3.2.5)
activesupport (3.2.5)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.18)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.5)
railties (3.2.5)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.19)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.15.2)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.4)
```

Comment: You have probably forgot to add the rvm script to your bash profile/rc file.

Comment: You can also put it in `/etc/profile.d` where on most systems that auto-loads.

Comment: Can you post an example of /etc/profile.d with rvm script please?

Answer (score 7):

Add this to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
[[ -s "/home/yourusername/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/yourusername/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Terminal`->`Edit`->`Profile Preferences`->`Title and Command`->`Run command as a login shell`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need edit ur terminal settings

just try
https://beatreader.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/ruby-on-rails-problemmissing-after-reboot/
or
You need to run this code everytime you open for terminal

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```